# How can i create and mantain a session with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a question:

I created, with http package, two http calls for a json file.
The first call is a post call, where i create the products:

```
Future<http.Response> AddPro(String title) async {
  final response = await http.post(
    'jsonurl',
    headers: <String, String>{
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      "title": title,
    }),
);
return response;}
```

And the second call, a get call, where i callback created products:

```
Future<List<ListC>> fetchListC(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
      await http.get('jsonurl');
  return compute(parseListC, response.body);
}

List<ListC> parseListC(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<ListC>((json) => ListC.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

The problem is that the second call, the get call, doesn't work correctly, because in the response of it, there are not the products created in the post call.
Probably is a problem with the session id(???), how can i create and mantain the same session for each call?

My error is:

```
I/flutter (15399): Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments.     
I/flutter (15399): Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:6
I/flutter (15399): Tried calling: cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
I/flutter (15399): Found: cast<RK, RV>() => Map<RK, RV>
```

I have this problem ONLY when i do a POST call to create products and a GET call to fetch them... it is as if flutter can't remember the created products... because with postman all works correctly

Maybe they have different headers?

Comment: Your json url is working ?

Comment: should have nothing to do with"sessions". THe URL you are posting to, where does it retain the data?

Comment: @OldProgrammer It is WooCommerce Rest Api... All works fine with postman

Comment: @dm_tr Yes my json url is working... i tried to do the get call and the post call with postman and it works fine... and in the flutter code the post call replies with the status code 201...so it works... but i can't fetch data with the get call (only in flutter), i don't know why...

Comment: You sure your get request has all the same headers as for postman?  Maybe try running fiddler to see that actual HTTP data flow

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thank you... i can't see the actual HTTP data flow now... but i added the error code